# prohibit .doc/.zip attachments in sendmail

Tags: sendmail

How do you prohibit .doc and .zip attachments with sendmail 8.14?

I'm looking for a solution that will automatically fail to accept a message in the presence of such an attachment, never accepting any such message for delivery in the first place.

Comment: @EEAA, did google of the title, looked at faq.  on what basis you, presumably, are voting to close this?

Comment: Here's the close reason I selected: "Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers."

Comment: The specific "desired end state" is very clearly and unambiguously stated in my question.  What exactly am I being unclear about?

Comment: "...and attempted solutions."

Comment: @EEAA, come on; this is sendmail!  What kind of solutions a non-novice user may one attempt prior to asking for some help? (-:

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, I don't think SendMail has the ability to natively block messages containing specific attachment name/type patterns.  For something like this, you'd need to leverage a sendmail milter (for which there are [many](https://www.milter.org/)).

Which milter is right for you depends on your requirements, preferences, infrastructure, and business use case so unfortunately I can't be any more specific than that.